# Should Restart celery beat after restart celery workers?

Tags: celery, celerybeat

i have two systemd service 
one handles my celery workers(10 queue for different tasks) and one handles celery beat

after deploying new code i restart celery worker service to get new tasks and update celery jobs

Should i restart celery beat with celery worker service too?

or it gets new tasks automatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what type of scheduler you're using.

If it's default [`PersistentScheduler`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.beat.html#celery.beat.PersistentScheduler) then yes, you need to restart beat daemon to allow it to pick up new configuration from the [`beat_schedule`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-beat_schedule) setting.

But if you're using something like [`django-celery-beat`](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat) which allows managing periodic tasks at runtime then you don't have to restart celery beat.